# How does Freenet maintain access to 'freesites' while retaining plausible deniability about content?

Tags: encryption, freenet

On Freenet you can host websites deemed '*freesites*' which are publicly accessible by everyone. As I understand, Freenet can serve a variety of content, some which is illegal, which is why content is encrypted on the users computer to ensure **plausible deniability**.

If this is so, how can many people access a freesite if they aren't the author (and can't decrypt it)?

Answer (score 4):

Below I have supplied the "basic" information required to achieve "understanding" of how the data is stored a accessed; this information has come directly from the Freenet web site. I would suggest viewing the following, ["Understand Freenet"](https://freenetproject.org/understand.html) ,if you wish to read further.

***How can many people access a freesite if they aren't the author (and can't decrypt it)?***

> **The Datastore**
>
> All Freenet nodes contribute with a part of their harddrive space to
>   store files. The files are stored encrypted in the store-directory in
>   the Freenet installation directory.
>
> Unlike other peer-to-peer networks, you as a user has little or no
>   control over what is stored in your datastore. Instead, files are kept
>   or deleted depending on how popular they are. This is to ensure that
>   Freenet is censorship resistant. The only possible way to remove
>   something from Freenet is to not search for it, and hope that
>   everybody else does the same.
>
> It is hard, but not impossible, to determine which files that are
>   stored in your local Freenet Datastore. This is to enable plausible
>   deniability as to what kind of material that lies on your harddrive in
>   the datastore.
>
> The initial diskspace allocated for the datastore is 5% of available
>   disk space if it is over 20GB, 10% if it is over 10GB, 512MB if under
>   10GB, and 256MB if under 5GB. You can change the store size at any
>   time, the more the better, both for your personal browsing and for
>   Freenet as a whole.
>
> **Freenet Routing**
>
> Initially, each node has no information about the performance of the
>   other nodes it knows about. This means that routing of requests is
>   essentially random. But since different nodes have different
>   randomness, they will disagree about where to send a request, given a
>   key. So the data in a newly-started Freenet will be distributed
>   somewhat randomly.
>
> As more documents are inserted by the same node, they will begin to
>   cluster with data items whose keys (see below) are similar, because
>   the same routing rules are used for all of them. More importantly, as
>   data items and requests from different nodes "cross paths", they will
>   begin to share clustering information as well.
>
> The result is that the network will self-organize into a distributed,
>   clustered structure where nodes tend to hold data items that are close
>   together in key space. There will probably be multiple such clusters
>   throughout the network, any given document being replicated numerous
>   times, depending on how much it is used.
>
> **Freenet keys**
>
> Each file that exists on Freenet has a key associated with it. Freenet
>   0.7 has various types of keys. Keys are used for everything on freenet, and are a kind of URI (e.g. freenet:=KSK@sample.txt).
>
> Most keys are hashes: there is no notion of semantic closeness when
>   speaking of key closeness. Therefore there will be no correlation
>   between key closeness and similar popularity of data as there might be
>   if keys did exhibit some semantic meaning, thus avoiding bottlenecks
>   caused by popular subjects.

If you are interested, here is a direct link to Ian Clarke's paper ["Freenet: A Distributed Anonymous Information Storage and Retrieval System"](http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~ghosh/freenet.pdf) hosted by the computer science department at the University of Iowa.